# SublimeText:Redirect cmdlime output to file is not happening

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

[
        { "command": "menu_exec", "args": {"cmd": "process.exe $file >out.txt"}, "caption": "RunP"},
]

Comment: Are you sure it's not just writing to a directory you're not looking in? Try specifying a full path instead of just `out.txt` and see if it writes to that.

Comment: @taylorthurlow tried that too. Not working

Comment: How about removing the extra comma after `"RunP"}`? Trailing commas is invalid JSON.

Comment: You should also add a little more information about your problem. Does it work without the output redirect? What even is the JSON for? I would assume a build system, but it does not look like it fits the syntax in [the Sublime Text guide on topic](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html).

Comment: Comma is there. Without re-direct everything is fine. But I want to re-direct to a file

Comment: In order to have shell redirections work you should use the `shell_cmd` argument to `exec` and not `cmd`; `cmd` is for directly executing programs and bypassing the shell.

Comment: Note also that Sublime's internal JSON parser is more tolerant than standard; trailing commas are OK as are comments. Also, this question is related to the plugin from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934013/sublimetext-run-the-exec-with-current-file-as-arg-tab-context-menu), which is not outlined above.

Comment: @OdatNurd, Yes.. using the same plugin from this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934013/sublimetext-run-the-exec-with-current-file-as-arg-tab-context-menu

Comment: And tried with shell_cmd. I get ""Access is denied."". May be I'm system is not allowing this "'shell"access ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to try it will a fully qualified output file that you're redirecting to; my guess is that since you're not using `working_dir` it is perhaps defaulting to a location you can't create files in, like the installation folder of Sublime or something. It's hard to say without seeing the actual error output though.